# vertical curly braces with node centre connection in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, flow-charts

I'm using TikZ to create a flowchart. I need a curly brace which centre is connected to `l1` node, start from `bl1.north west` to `m3.south west`.
Here is my code illustrating the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\centering
\pagestyle{empty}

\tikzstyle{startsetup} = [rectangle, draw, text width=10cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1em, fill=blue!20]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width = 3.5cm, text centered, minimum height = 3em, fill= red!20]
\tikzstyle{lblock} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1em, fill=yellow!20]
\tikzstyle{DCS} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1em, fill=orange!50]
\tikzstyle{server} = [rectangle, draw, text width=3.5cm, text centered, minimum height=1em, fill=green!20]

\begin{tikzpicture}[ align=center,decoration={brace}] %node distance=2cm and 4cm,

\node (m1) [startsetup] {Preagreement and Travel Preperation};
\node (m2) [startsetup, below of= m1,node distance=1.5cm] {Site Visit \& Technical Assessment};
\node (bl1) [block, below left =2cm and -2cm of m2  ] {Software exist on CPU and could be uploaded}; %2cm and 0.5cm of
\node (br1) [block, below right=2cm and -2cm of m2 ] {Software is not exist};
\node (br2) [block, below of= br1, node distance=2cm ] {HAZOP, SRS,FSMR to be revised};
\node (br3) [server, below of= br2, node distance=2cm ] {HIMA server and licence preparation};
\node (br4) [block, below of= br3, node distance=2cm ] {Design,Implement logic functions and software assessment};
\node (br5) [DCS, below of= br4, node distance=3cm ] {Pre-commissioning and I/O check \\ \&\\ DCS communication link};
\node (br5) [DCS, below of= br4, node distance=3cm ] {Pre-commissioning and I/O check \\ \&\\ DCS communication link};
\node (m3) [startsetup, below left=3cm and -3cm of br5 ] {Complete SAT procedure \\ \& \\Start UP};

\node (bl2) [block, below of= bl1, node distance= 2cm ] {Logic Function logics asseessment on local licenced machine};
\node (bl3) [server, below of= bl2, node distance= 2cm ] {HIMA server and licence preparation};
\node (bl4) [DCS, below of= bl3, node distance=3cm ] {Pre-commissioning and I/O check \\ \&\\ DCS communication link};

\node (l1) [lblock,left  of=bl3,node distance=8cm] { text};

%Flows

\draw [thick, ->] (m1) -- (m2);
\draw [thick, ->] (m2.south) -- ++(0,-1cm) -|node [above] {path(1)}(bl1);
\draw [thick, ->] (m2.south) -- ++(0,-1cm) -|node [above] {path(2)}(br1);
\draw [thick, ->] (bl1) -- (bl2);
\draw [thick, ->] (bl2) -- (bl3);
\draw [thick, ->] (bl3) -- (bl4);

\draw [thick, ->] (br1) -- (br2);
\draw [thick, ->] (br3) -- (br4);
\draw [thick, ->] (br4) -- (br5);

\draw [very thick, orange, ->] (bl4.south) --++(0,-2.5cm) -| (m3);
\draw [very thick, orange, ->] (br5.south) --++(0,-0.668cm) -| (m3);

%\draw [thick,orange, ->] (bl4.south)   -- ++(0,-2cm) -- ++(2cm,0)-- ++(0,-2.82cm);%(bl4.south)   --++(0,-1cm)-|(m3.north west)
%\draw [thick, orange,->] (br5.south) --++(0,-1cm) --++(-1cm,0) --++(0,-2cm); %\draw [thick, orange,->] (br5.south)  --++(0,-1cm) -|(m3);
%\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3mm}](bl1)--node[right,anchor=south west] {$\log_{3/2}n$}(m3);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=20pt,mirror},xshift=4pt,yshift=0pt]
(bl1.north west) -- (m3.south west) node [black,midway,xshift=-3cm]
{};
%\node at (l1) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=20pt,mirror},xshift=4pt,yshift=0pt]
(bl1.north -| bl4.west) -- (m3.south -| bl4.west) node [black,midway,xshift=-3cm]
{};
```

if it do what you like to have:

[image]

i play with your *mwe* a little bit ... see if obtained code is interesting for you:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[%showframe,
            margin=1.5cm,
            landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                positioning}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{FlowChart/.style = {
   supress join/.code = {\def\tikz@after@path{}},
    start/.style args = {##1/##2}{rectangle, rounded corners, draw,
        text width=##1, minimum height=8mm,
        fill=##2,
        align=flush center, inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm,
        on chain, join=by LA},
       start/.default = 80mm/blue!30,
%
    block/.style args = {##1/##2}{rectangle, draw,
        text width=##1, minimum height=16mm,
        fill=##2,
        align=flush center, inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm,
        on chain, join=by LA},
    block/.default=34mm/red!30,
%
             B/.style = {decorate,
        decoration={brace,amplitude=4mm, raise=2mm,
                    ##1} },
           B/.default = mirror,
            LA/.style = {-Triangle,thick}
                        }% end of FlowChart style
        }% end of tikzset
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
    node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
      start chain = going below
                    ]
\node (m1)  [start] {Preagreement and Travel Preperation};
\node (m2)  [start] {Site Visit \& Technical Assessment};

% left branch
\node (bl1) [block, supress join,
             below left=of m2.south]
                    {Software exist on CPU and could be uploaded};
\node (bl2) [block] {Logic Function logics asseessment on local licenced machine};
\node (bl3) [block=32mm/green!30]
                    {HIMA server and licence preparation};
\node (bl4) [start=42mm/orange!30]
                    {Pre-commissioning and I/O check \\ \&\\ DCS communication link};

% right branch
\node (br1) [block, supress join,
             below right=of m2.south]
                    {Software is not exist};
\node (br2) [block] {HAZOP, SRS,FSMR to be revised};
%
\node (br3) [block=32mm/green!30]
                    {HIMA server and licence preparation};
\node (br4) [block,] {Design,Implement logic functions and software assessment};
\node (br5) [start=42mm/orange!30]
                {Pre-commissioning and I/O check \\
                 \&\\
                 DCS communication link};

% midle branch again
\node (m3) [start, supress join,
            below=of m2 |- br5.south]
                {Complete SAT procedure \\
                 \& \\
                 Start UP};
%Flows
\draw [thick] (m2.south) -- ++(0,-3mm) coordinate (aux1);
\draw[LA]   (aux1) -| (bl1);
\draw[LA]   (aux1) -| (br1);
\draw [very thick, orange]
        (br5.south) -- ++ (0,-3mm) -| coordinate[pos=0.25] (aux2) (bl4);
\draw [LA, very thick, orange]
        (aux2) -- (m3);
\draw [B]   (bl1.north -| bl4.west) --
            node (l1) [block=32mm/yellow!30, supress join,
                       left=1cm] {some text?}
            (m3.south -| bl4.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addedndum:**

regarding your additional questions in comment below, i can give you due to lack of information, only general advises about structure of document:

```
\documentclass[....]{....}
% used packages

%tikzsets (i) for FlowChart, (ii) for ...

\begin{document}
%document body

\begin{figure}
    \input{flowchart-1}% name of file in which you store flowchart code
\caption{May important flowchart :-)}
\label{fig:flowchart-1}
\end{figure}

% other text
\end{document}
```

file `flowchart-1` (supposed, that this is file name of image) had to start with `\begin{tikzpicture}` and end with `tikzpicture`.

beside this rude method you should consider use of the `standalone` package in your workflow. but this (as whole addendum) is out of your question context. if you have problems with this, please ask new question, that more people will see it an be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zarko.
The only part remained is how I can *connect* the centre of *curly brace* to the centre of `l1`block( `l1.east`). unbalance curly brace

Comment: @Shahram, see edited answer.

Comment: if I want to add this flowchart `\input{flowchart.tex}`directly into my master *LaTeX* document, which part of this file to be deleted?

Comment: `tikset` should be in document's preamble (that can be used for other similar images), image file, is between `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: used `\input{flowchart.tex}`into my master LaTeX file added your comments:
1. cannot add `\caption` & `\label`to reference this flowchart into the document.     
2. changed the original flows.
! /Users/shahramkarimi/Desktop/dump.png

Comment: @Shahram, how you include this image to your document before my answer?  what you ask here in comments seems to be new question. to advise you, i have not enough information about your workflow, and document (project) organization.  see addendum in my answer (will appear soon).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68552/discussion-between-shahram-and-zarko).